# Netbeans warning: "Unknown Property ..."

Tags: svg, netbeans-8

I use Netbean 8.1 to create a Web project (PHP language). 
I get many "Unknown property" warnings in my source. 
[image]

Will it cause any negative impact on my project? 
How to fix this warning?

Comment: Netbeans is open source so presumably you could modify it to support SVG in CSS.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you show me how to modify CSS Netbeans?

Comment: No, that's far too broad.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I will learn about it.